# using Ninject in project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I want to use Ninject in my project,this is my code :

```
public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
private IKernel ninjectKernel;
public NinjectControllerFactory()
{
  ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
  AddBindings();
}

  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContextrequestContext,      Type controllerType)
```

{
      return (controllerType == null) ? null :(IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

```
 private void AddBindings()
 {

   ninjectKernel.Bind<IHomeService>().To<HomeService>();
   ninjectKernel.Bind<IHomeBussiness>().To<HomeBussiness>();
 }

  }
```

and my global.asax is :

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

and my home controller is:

```
    private readonly IHomeService _iHomeService;
    public HomeController(IHomeService iHomeService)
    {
        _iHomeService = iHomeService;
    }
```

and now :

When I run My project I see that say Does not exist StandardProvider.cs
[image]

and my error is:

```
Error activating ObjectContext using implicit self-binding of ObjectContext
Several constructors have the same priority. Please specify the constructor using      ToConstructor syntax or add an Inject attribute.
```

how can I Resolve this Issue?